# In Sencha Touch is it possible to flick past the last item back to the start of a carousel?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm new to Sencha Touch have a bit of an issue. Quite simply I've got 9 images of a person and I want to use the carousel to turn the person around. I'm stuck on how the last image would then move straight onto the first with out having to scroll back. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check the [Infinite Carousel](http://www.simoens.org/Sencha-Projects/demos/) example of Simoen's. And the source code is [here](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.touch.InfiniteCarousel).

Comment: Wow thats exactly what I was looking for, I'm forever indebted!